# HMVC MY_Controller Parent Sessons Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to set up in my hmvc MY_Controller a codeigniter sessions redirect for whole website

but just loads the fire fox problem loading page message.

What do I do to make it work.

**Dashboard.php** Just sample

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {
 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('user');
  $this->lang->load('english', 'english');
  $this->lang->load('common/dashboard', 'english');
 }
}
```

**MY_Controller.php**

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
         return true;
      } else {
         redirect('login');
      }
   } 

}
```

I also tried this

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {

         redirect('/');
      }
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the **CSRF** enabled seem to be in conflict with it but now disabled the **CSRF** and working OK.